# Java BindException when trying to open/listen at port 4450 on CentOS

Tags: java, centos, port, serversocket

I am trying to open a port to listen on my CentOS VPS. I am using Java. The code I am using is here:

http://pastebin.com/GKgaxeaD

The error I am getting when I run it is here:

```
at CommandListener.run(CommandListener.java:27)
at java.net.ServerSocket.(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

Why would I be getting this error? Nothing is using the port (4450). There doesn't seem to be a firewall or anything blocking the port either, but I'm not 100% sure about this.

Comment: What is the output of running 'nmap -sT -O localhost' on your system.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/YBYyUsUG     "Not shown: 995 closed ports"..strange. So what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please run 
 lsof -i:4450
in terminal(console) to check who used this port

Comment: Nothing happened when I ran this. It just went to the next entry line in the terminal.